Does the Copy and Swap idiom have a not-required swap?
In an answer to this question, under the label: "Why does that work?" , it was noted that:

Now, if other is being initialized with an rvalue, it will be move-constructed. Perfect. In the same way C++03 let us re-use our copy-constructor functionality by taking the argument by-value, C++11 will automatically pick the move-constructor when appropriate as well. (And, of course, as mentioned in previously linked article, the copying/moving of the value may simply be elided altogether.)

But, even when utilizing the move-constructor (which means, even when receiving a rvalue object), the assignment operator will do an additional, unrequired swap (one swap in the move-constructor, second one in the assignment-operator). But in this case, wouldn't just overloading the move-assignment-operator will spare us this swap?
Because, as you can see, the move-assignment-operator will only do one swap:
dumb_array& operator=(dumb_array&& other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}


Hence, wouldn't we save one swap if we were to overload the move-assignment-operator too? --  The move assignment operator would still need to manage the resource that this currently holds.   For example, delete [] would still have to be called for a member allocated with new[].  Your version with only a swap doesn't do this.

@PaulMcKenzie -- But wouldn't other, which is an rvalue object, get destroyed after the move-assignment automatically, because it is an rvalue?

@CSStudent Not necessarily. Consider: dumb_array a = SomeInitializer; dumb_array b = AnotherInitializer; b = std::move(a); Here, a could live arbitrarily long afterwards, carrying resources that used to belong to b. Sometimes it doesn't matter, other times it may (e.g. destroying the contents of b could have observable side effects).

@IgorTandetnik -- Alright, thanks. I never thought about that you can "explicitly" call the move-assignment-constructor on objects which are lvalue, by casting the objects to rvalue objects.

Paul Mckenzie "Your version with only a swap doesn't do this" - yes, it does, provided dumb_array implements the Rule of 5 correctly. The current resource would be swapped into other, which will then free the resource when other is destroyed eventually.  It may not be optimal to swap the current resource into the object that is being moved from, but it should work nonetheless.

@RemyLebeau -- But in the meantime, because a stores b's data now, it means that data which is considered to be inaccessible (b's previous data) is now accessible (via a). So what I wrote should work, but it has a remarkable flaw.

@CSStudent A program that would access that old data via a would exhibit undefined or at best unspecified behavior, by way of read after move. A moved-from object is considered to be in a valid but unspecified state.

@CSStudent "it means that data which is considered to be inaccessible" -- It is not considered inaccessible. "Inaccessible" is a known state, while the result of a move involves an unknown state (in the absence of further documentation).

Copy+swap is a beginner level idiom, mostly targeting rule 3; it usually leads to resource correct - but not always optimum - implementation. Move semantics is mostly about ownership or optimization. So when user provides a definition for move ctor or move assignment, he has already switched to rule 5, and needs to pay caution to every corner. std::vector is an example of rule 5 avoiding copy+swap, because it would waste cpu cycles.

@Red.Wave -- May you please explain a bit more? I can't quite understand the essence of what you say.

Use copy+swap only when you don't need to define move constructor+assignment operator. Move semantics is meant for optimization; thus your copy assignment too has to be optimized. Otherwise there's no point in defining move functions for an already copyable class. std::vector and std::string are examples of cases where copy+swap would lead to missed optimization. Copy assignment would always cause an allocation and a deallocation, whilest in case of enough capacity simple element-wise copy can be much faster. Even for move assignment, simple swapping could dealloate the larger buffer.
